# How to display UPDATE results immediatly

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

So here below i'm calling a query to update the slack_id. This is in the backend Index.js file. The /update is being called In the CRUD.js frontend in the next code segment.

```
app.put("/update", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.body.id;
  const slack_id = req.body.slack_id;
  db.query( "UPDATE developers SET slack_id = ? WHERE id = ?",[slack_id, id],
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.send(result);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

The /update is called here. After the Axios.put I'm trying to put in a statement that can display the results immediatly without the need to refresh my page. I cant figure out how though. The setdeveloperList contains the values `name, slack_id, selected, absent`
I'm updating the slack_id here.

```
const updateDeveloper = (id) => {
  Axios.put(`${url}/update`, { slack_id: newSlackID, id: id }).then(() => {
      setdeveloperList(
        developerList.filter((val) => {
        return val.id !== id;
        })
      )
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

So I found out myself.

```
const updateDeveloper = (id) => {
  Axios.put(`${url}/update`, { slack_id: newSlackID, id: id }).then(
    (response) => {
      setdeveloperList(
        developerList.map((val) => {
          return val.id === id
            ? {
                id: val.id,
                slack_id: newSlackID,
                name: val.name,
                selected: val.selected,
                absent: val.absent
              }
            : val;
        })
      );
    }
  );
  };
```

^^ This works